# What happens to the data that my ajax requested if the browser closed and there is nothing to receive it

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sql

In my web site (vb.net / c# ) there is javascript ajax code that gets data from the database and returns JSON to my page.

What happens if just before the ajax is about to receive the JSON, the browser is closed or the page was redirected, what happens to that data as there was nothing to receive it?

I can see that because its asynchronous  the vb.net carries on running and sends a response.  but there was nothing to receive it - what happens to the responses.

It cant just vanish into thin air - technically what happens - will my server crash?

Comment: it vanishes as far as the user is concerned

Answer (score 6):

They get sucked into the void, never to be seen or heard of again.

That is, your client pc will still receive the packets via TCP/IP, but the TCP/IP stack will not deliver them anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - so if the stack will not deliver them  - then what happens - will the browser crash or is it automatically disposed of by the browser? and what if the browser is gone?

Comment: The TCP/IP stack is hosted by the OS, not the browser, so the browser is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Garbage collector dismantles the whole deal.

Once the HttpContext and Session end from the user closing their browser, only requests which have started will continue. They will return data like someone yelling out into the night. The next ones will more than likely be garbage collected because the Session has ended and there is no longer a need to service the thread.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the hosting OS, where the browser has been running, gets the TCP/IP response from the Server and discards it as there's no application waiting for this data.